# what lock will mysql issue for 'load data infile' on innodb?

Tags: locking, innodb

I'm using `LOAD DATA INFILE` on an InnoDB table, and I see "System lock" status in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`. What lock exactly does InnoDB lock in this situation? How can I check what is locked?

Comment: `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` will report on the locks, somewhere in the midst of the ton of info it outputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two parts to your question: What does `LOAD DATA INFILE` actually lock in InnoDB, and how can you examine locks.

The `LOAD DATA INFILE` command is basically just a slightly more efficient way to do a multi-row `INSERT`, and it will lock exactly the same things as the `INSERT` would. As the `LOAD DATA INFILE` is processed, for each index in the table being loaded into, the key from the row being loaded is locked with an exclusive row lock.

While the `LOAD DATA INFILE` is running, you will be able to see some overall statistics about its locking with `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. If you enable the [InnoDB lock monitor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-monitors.html) you can see more detail about each individual lock taken (up to a point).

Comment: this is exactly what I want thank you. Just to double check, since 'LOAD DATA INFILE' is locking the same as 'INSERT', then if there's no index on the table, there will be no lock, is that right?

Comment: There is always a clustered key in InnoDB. If you don't specify a `PRIMARY KEY` (or a suitable `UNIQUE KEY`) then a hidden "row ID" field is added to the table and used for the clustered key. Normally you should always define a `PRIMARY KEY`, and potentially delay adding other keys until after the data is loaded.